# Were Tina Fey and John Cena "digitally enhanced" in Sisters (2015)?

Tags: character, effects, sisters

In Sisters (2015) there are some scenes where both Cena and Fey appear to be ... bigger than usual; Particularly in this image:
[image]

Tina appears to have a bigger chest than on the rest of the movie or just from regular photographs:
[image]

Cena on the other hand appears to be taller and more muscular:
[image]

Were they digitally edited or was it just a fine good job of wardrobe + makeup + lights?

Comment: TBH I don't see anything out of the ordinary here. Fey is presumably wearing a push-up bra, and Cena is crossing his arms which makes his muscles look bigger.

Comment: Push Up Bra, Makeup/shading, and posture. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mt1eG1g9vNY http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2377489/How-shots-used-aggressive-marketing-sell-new-diets-fitness-regimes-big-con.html

Comment: I suppose Tina Fey is still hot then o.o

Comment: Do you have any clue how expensive this would be to do digitally? This is a comedy film... it doesn't have a budget big enough to pay for that. A push-up bra and some falsies cost $50. Why would they pay millions to do it digitally?

Comment: You seriously asking us about someone's chest size?

Comment: I don't get it. The muscles and head size look about normal for Cena, and Fey is just wearing a push-up. Where's the enhancement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tina's just wearing a particularly dutiful push-up, but John Cena was actually standing on something to appear ridiculously tall; even larger-than-life than he normally is (this was revealed in the DVD commentary of Sisters; it was actually Tina Fey's idea for him to stand on a box and look even taller).